# Count function to find people with ten references

Tags: sql, oracle-sqldeveloper

need a bit of help regarding university work. (I am using SQL developer)

Basically, the question is 'Find the different first keywords associated with references by prolific authors who have more than ten references'

So far I have only been able to do:

```
select surname, count(surname)from librarian.readings
group by surname
having count(surname) > 10
```

which gives me

```
SURNAME    COUNT(SURNAME)
---------- --------------
White      16
Marble     11
Peuquet    14
Robinson   12
Rhind      15
```

However, this doesn't give me the keywords associated with it

```
select distinct surname,key1 
from librarian.readings
```

but this just gives me too much information.
How do I do this?

Comment: It'd be helpful to put the table schemas. I'm assuming there's a table where 'keywords' is a column? Or a keywords column?

Comment: What is the result supposed to look like? Just key1 of the 68 readings? Or those keys, each along with its author? Or one row per author with a string listing all their keys? Or something else still?

Comment: There are 4 tables regarding keywords: key1, key2, key3 and key4. Sorry if i'm not much help. Completely new to this. Enjoying it though and thanks  for the help

Answer (score 0):

This is assuming that surname is a unique field;

```
SELECT
r.surname
,r.key1
FROM librarian.readings r
INNER JOIN (select 
                surname, 
                count(surname) surname_count 
            from librarian.readings
            group by surname) sub
    ON r.surname = sub.surname
WHERE sub.surname_count > 10
```

If Surname isn't unique then you need to do this by the primary key on librarian.readings.

Answer (score 0):

If all you need is the distinct keywords associated with .... then:

```
select distinct key1 
from librarian.readings 
group by surname
having count(*) > 10
```